# extracting a single data from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do you extract a value (string) from a given Dataframe, given a certain value from a different column.

For example, I would like to get the 'Adrs' where 'Value'=2

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Adrs':["AAA","BBB"],'Value':[1,2]}, index=[0,1])

print(df)
print("")

df2 = df[df['Value']==2]
string = df2.Adrs
print(string)
```

Output:

```
Adrs  Value
0  AAA      1
1  BBB      2

1    BBB
Name: Adrs, dtype: object
```

I would like to extract just the "BBB" instead of that entire table/data frame.  Is there a quick way to do this without doing some parsing of the df2.Adrs

If df2 has multiple rows, I can extract BBB by df2['Adrs'][1]

see below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Adrs':["AAA","BBB"],'Value':[2,2]}, index=[0,1])

print(df)
print("")

df2 = df[df['Value']==2]
string = str(df2['Adrs'][1])
print(string)
```

output:

```
 Adrs  Value
0  AAA      2
1  BBB      2

BBB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> df.loc[df['Value'] == 2, 'Adrs'].values[0]
'BBB'
>>> df.iat[1, 0]
'BBB'
>>> df.at[1, 'Adrs']
'BBB'
```

Are a few ways. I'm sure there's more.

Comment: the .iat and .at works but only if you know the exact location in the data frame.  But the first code you gave works well for what i want.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

df2.Adrs is still a Series, so what you want to do is grab one element from it.  df2.Adrs.iloc(0) will get you the first element, regardless of indexing.  But what will you do if df2 has multiple rows?

Comment: i get "<pandas.core.indexing._iLocIndexer object at 0x000000000506C550>" using df2.Adrs.iloc(0) . When df2 has multiple rows, i can get the data by df2['Adrs'][x], depending on what row.  See the updated question