# Extract values from WaldTestResults pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statsmodels

After applying statsmodels.api.Logit I get the output of the logistic model.

```
LogModel = sm.Logit(y_01, Xdata_WithDummies).fit()        
walds = LogModel.wald_test_terms()
```

Among the computed statistics there is a Wald Test table given as a pandas Dataframe (<class 'statsmodels.stats.contrast.WaldTestResults'>), that I can print and see it. However, I need to extract specific elements of this table for further analysis. According to the [help page](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults.wald_test_terms.html#statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults.wald_test_terms) the Wald table is a pandas DataFrame.

I did not manage to transform this table into a list (list(wald), TypeError: 'WaldTestResults' object is not iterable) nor to see its values by wald.values (error: AttributeError: 'WaldTestResults' object has no attribute 'values') nor to extract a specific column (TypeError: 'WaldTestResults' object is not subscriptable), or even to extract specific values out of the table following relevant advice (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074820/extracting-a-single-data-from-pandas-data-frame)).

How could I read specific values out of this table? Or (equivalently) how could I transform this table into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert it to a `pandas.DataFrame` you need to use the `.summary_frame()` method.

#### Sample Data

```
import statsmodels.api as sm 
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, 50)
x = np.random.randint(0, 2, (50, 3))
```

---

#### Code

```
LogModel = sm.Logit(y, x).fit()        
walds = LogModel.wald_test_terms()

df = walds.summary_frame()
#    chi2  P>chi2  df constraint
#x1   0.0     1.0              1
#x2   0.0     1.0              1
#x3   0.0     1.0              1

type(df)
#pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```